# Como puedo utilizar los métodos de la clase en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, poo, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente código, ahora deseo calcular la distancia entre los puntos que he creado, pero no encuentro la forma de invocar el método distancia...

```
<?php
       class puntoR2{
            public $x;
            public $y; 

        public function __construct($x, $y){
            $this->x = $x;
            $this->y =$y;
        }

        public function mostrar(){
            echo "El par ordenado es: ($this->x, $this->y)";
        }

        public function distancia($a1, $b1){
            $dx = $a1 -> $this->x - $b1 -> $this->x;
            $dy = $a1 -> $this->y - $b1 -> $this->y;
            $distancia = sqrt($dx*$dx + $dy*$dy);
            echo "La distancia entre los puntos es: $distancia";
        }
    }
   
$p1 = new puntoR2(5, 4);
$p2 = new puntoR2(4, 8);
    ?>
```

Comment: marca `distancia` como estática asi la podes llamar sin instanciar `puntoR2::distancia($p1,$p2)`, en el calculo de `$dx` y `$dy` no haría falta el `$this` pq estarías accediendo a `->x` e `->y` de `$a` y `$b`

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que quieres. Un `Punto` tendría dos coordenadas, y por lo general se calcula la distancia entre esas dos coordenadas. Pero pareces hablar de calcular la distancia entre dos instancias de la clase `Punto` ¿?

Comment: se asume R2 refiere a [plano cartesiano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_coordenado_real#n_=_2) por tanto distancia entre dos puntos del espacio euclídeo equivale a la longitud del segmento de la recta que los une, expresado numéricamente. para puntos con 2 coordenadas se resolvería [via pitágoras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distancia#Distancia_de_dos_puntos_en_el_plano)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podría ser

- Puedes crear una función `distanciaCon` para comparar la distancia del punto con otro punto.
- Puedes crear una función estática que compare la distancia de 2 puntos

(Yo mezcle ambos métodos)

Además corregí tu función distancia, tu tenias:

```
$dx = $a1 -> $this->x - $b1 -> $this->x;
```

Y debería ser:

```
$dx = $a1->x - $b1->x;
```

```
<?php

     class puntoR2{
            public $x;
            public $y; 

        public function __construct($x, $y){
            $this->x = $x;
            $this->y =$y;
        }

        public function mostrar(){
            echo "El par ordenado es: ($this->x, $this->y)";
        }

       public function distanciaCon($b1){
            return puntoR2::distancia($this,$b1);
        }

        public static function distancia($a1, $b1){
            $dx = $a1->x - $b1->x;
            $dy = $a1->y - $b1->y;
            return sqrt($dx*$dx + $dy*$dy);
        }
    }
   
$p1 = new puntoR2(5, 4);
$p2 = new puntoR2(4, 8);

echo "La distancia entre los puntos es:". $p1->distanciaCon($p2); //La distancia entre los puntos es:4.1231056256177

echo "La distancia entre los puntos es:". puntoR2::distancia($p1,$p2); // La distancia entre los puntos es:4.1231056256177
```